# Connect to remote Access 2003 database which has linked tables

Tags: c#, ms-access-2003, linked-tables

I've got this scenario: I developed a C# application which connect to a mdb file (Access 2003) through OleDBConnection (engine = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0). This mdb file has some linked tables in another mdb file in the same directory. Everything works perfectly in the local environment, the query retrieves data from linked table even if I connect only the main mdb file. A simplified schema could be:

my application in the local machine --> C:\mydir\main.mdb --> C:\mydir\linked_tables.mdb

But this application should work in some host computers of a local network. And the mdb files are stored in a server in a shared directory. Well, when the application is running in a host I set the path as follow:

\\myserver\mydir\main.mdb

The connection works. The problem happens when I launch a query which tries to get data from linked tables. It tries to find the linked table in C:\mydir\linked_tables.mdb, but this path is on the server, not in the host.

Is there a way to tell him: if the path of the main mdb file is \\myserver\mydir\main.mdb you must (automatically) get the linked tables on \\myserver\mydir\linked_tables.mdb?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved with another connection. I mean: for each mdb file I use a different OleDBConnection.

```
OleDbConnection MainConn = new OleDbConnection("\\myserver\mydir\main.mdb");
OleDbConnection LinkedTablesConn = new OleDbConnection("\\myserver\mydir\linked_tables.mdb");
```

Not so elegant, but it works. If I have to do some join of tables located in different databases, I manage them with some generic collection objects.